# Umbraco 5 reading Home page children using REST service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, umbraco, umbraco-blog

I am currently working on an **Umbraco 4 to 5 migration project**. I am stuck with reading the Home page childrens via  **REST service** of an Umbraco 5 site (for navigation). I knew that the REST services can be exposed via MVC areas/routes and controller actions, and 
using **hive** to get **data from Umbraco** . I used to get the data from Umbraco 4 with the following code

```
var nodes = uQuery.GetNodesByXPath(
"//root/descendant-or-self::* [@isDoc and (@level = 2) and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']"
```

I tried with the following code to fetch the data and it is not working

```
        var childs = RoutableRequestContext.Application.Hive.GetReader(new Uri("content://"));

        using (var uow = childs.CreateReadonly<IContentStore>())
        {
            var childIds = uow.Repositories.GetChildRelations(FixedHiveIds.ContentRootSchema, FixedRelationTypes.DefaultRelationType)
                        .Select(x => x.DestinationId).ToArray();

            IEnumerable<TypedEntity> children = uow.Repositories.Get<TypedEntity>(true, childIds);
        }
```

Does anyone know how to **fetch** the data from **Umbraco5 using hive**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

`FixedHiveIds.ContentRootSchema`

try using the Id of the parent that you'd like to look within. If you're intending to use the root, it's: `FixedHiveIds.ContentVirtualRoot`

Answer (score 0):

Ever tried this?

```
RoutableRequestContext.Application.Hive.QueryContent();
RoutableRequestContext.Application.Hive.QueryMedia()
```